# React Native Expo: how can i store a snapshot?

Tags: mongodb, react-native, fetch, expo, snapshot

I'm using takeSnapshotAsync to take a snapshot of one of my components, this returns either a URI or a base64 of about 2.5 million characters. 
I need this image to be sent to a mongo database for storage.
However, the URI only points to a link on the phone it was taken on and I apparently can't just send the string using fetch..

How can I go about getting my snapshot either onto my database or at least to somewhere I could then save a link to on the database?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

switched to firebase, able to store and retrieve the base64 images